# I'm holding a Schengen visa as a student, do I need to apply for visa to another Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, study, long-stay-visas

I'm currently a foreign student holding my resident permit in a Schengen country, and I will go for student exchange next January to another Schengen country. As the exchange duration lasts longer than 90 days, do I need to apply for visa for my stay there?

Comment: This is more appropriate for expatriates.SE site rather then here.

Answer (score 4):

Your current residence permit only allows you to visit other Schengen countries for 90 days within a 180 days period. So if you want to stay more than 90 days in another Schengen country, you need to apply for a new national visa (type D) or a residence permit from that country.